# Find the position of a give data in the inorder traversal of a binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am searching for the position (index no) of a data in the in-order traversal of the Binary search tree.

```
void inorder(struct node *root) {    
  if(!root)
      return NULL;
  inorder(root->left);
  cout<<root->data;
  inorder(root->right);
}
```

How I can modify this function to get the position of a given number.

Comment: First of all, please format the code accordingly to the policies of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an integer by reference and increase it in your function:

```
void inorder(struct node *root, int &position){    
    if(!root)
        return NULL;
    inorder(root->left, position);
    position++;
    cout<<position<<": "<<root->data;
    inorder(root->right, position);
}
```